# Perl regex - why does the regex /[0-9\.]+(\,)/ match comma

Tags: regex, perl

The following seems to match `,`
Can someone explain why?

I would like to match more than one Number or point, ended by comma.

```
 123.456.768,
 123,
 .,
 1.2,
```

But doing the following unexpectedly prints `,` too

```
my $text = "241.000,00";
foreach my $match ($text =~ /[0-9\.]+(\,)/g){
    print "$match \n";
}
print $text; 

# prints 241.000,
#        ,
```

**Update:** 
The comma matched because:
`In list context, //g returns a list of matched groupings, or if there are no groupings, a list of matches to the whole regex`
As defined [here.](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrequick.html#More-matching)

Comment: You don't need to escape commas; and if you aren't going to capture them you don't want the parens. What exactly do you want to print/caputre?

Comment: Not sure what the question is here.  Your capturing group contains an escaped comma (not sure the backslash has any effect on a comma in Perl), so I would expect this to return a comma as the captured string.

Comment: Please edit your question to finish your thought - "How can I match more a group of numbers of length more than, which"... ?

Comment: I would like to match more than one number/point followed by a comma.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a [zero-width positive look-ahead assertion](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Look-Around-Assertions) to exclude the comma from the match itself:

```perl
$text =~ /[0-9\.]+(?=,)/g
```

Comment: It was not clear, that perl regexp returns only the matchpart, which is enclosed by `()`. I used them to group parts of the regexp. For this purposes non-matchin parenthesis exist: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13502565/how-to-get-a-list-matches-without-groupings

Answer (score 4):

Your match in the foreach loop is in list context.  In list context, a match returns what its captured.  Parens indicate a capture, not the whole regex.  You have parens around a comma.  You want it the other way around, put the parens aroundt he bit you want.

```
my $text = "241.000,00";

# my($foo) puts the right hand side in list context.
my($integer_part) = $text =~ /([0-9\.]+),/;

print "$integer_part\n";  # 241.000
```

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to match the comma, use a lookahead assertion:

```
/[0-9\.]+(?=,)/g
```

Answer (score 2):

You're capturing the wrong thing! Move the parens from around the comma to around the number.

```
$text =~ /([0-9\.]+),/g
```

Answer (score 1):

You can replace the comma with a lookahead, or just exclude the comma altogether since it isn't part of what you want to capture, it won't make a difference in this case. However, the pattern as it is puts the comma instead of the number into capture group 1, and then doesn't even reference by capture group, returning the entire match instead.

This is how a capture group is retrieved:

```
$mystring = "The start text always precedes the end of the end text.";
if($mystring =~ m/start(.*)end/) {
    print $1;
}
```