# How to get a list matches, without groupings?

Tags: regex, perl

In perl the following seems to return a list of matches **AND matched groupings!**

```
//g
```

Rule:

> In list context, `//g` returns a list of matched groupings, or if there are no groupings, a list of matches to the whole regex

How can I get a list of matches WITHOUT groupings?

**Update:**

In perl regexp seems to return everything what is matched by regexp parts eclosed in `()` plus what is matched by the whole term.

For grouping (not capturing) purposes, e.g. to write match "cat" or "dog" use `(?:cat|dog)`.
Using `(cat|dog)` and not `(?:cat|dog)` would add any occurence of "cat" or "dog" to the result list.

**Matching parenthesis: ( )**

```
"badcat and baddog" =~ /bad(cat|dog)/g
```

Results in: `(badcat baddog cat dog)` 
Single `cat` and `dog` are added to results list, because they are enclosed in **matching parentheises**

**Non matching parenthesis: (?: )**

```
 "badcat and baddog" =~ /bad(?:cat|dog)/g
```

Results in: `(badcat baddog)`

Comment: What exactly would a list of matches be, if not a list of matched groupings?

Comment: It should be the match of the WHOLE regex

Comment: Well, then don't use parentheses, just like the documentation says. If you need parens for other purposes, you can use non-capturing ones, `(?: ... )`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need parens for other purposes, you can use non-capturing ones, `(?: ... )`

Answer (score 1):

If you have a regular expression that may have groupings in it, but you only want matches for the entire regular expression, do something like this:

```
my $regex = qr/some regex (with) (groupings)/;
my @matches;
while ($string =~ m/($regex)/g) { push(@matches, $1) }
```

Inside the `while` loop `$1` is guaranteed to be the entire match of `$regex`.